# Drawing Shapes as values on ZingChart

Tags: javascript, zingchart

I have a requirement where my data values are two-dimensional objects I must draw in the chart (scatter):

[image: Rects as data]

On this chart, I have two values (red, and green), each one consisting of a rectangle with (x1,y1)-(x2-y2) coordinates.

Do you know how this can be achieved using the ZingChart Library?
Is it even possible?
If not, do you know an alternative javascript library I can use to implement this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm on the ZingChart team, and I'm happy to help you out. This is certainly possible using marker objects of type "poly". In the `points` array of the marker object, you need to specify all four points of the rectangle, which, altogether, would look something like this:

```
[ [x1, y1], [x1, y2], [x2, y2], [x2, y1] ]
```

Now, if you put your (x1, y1) values and (x2, y2) values into two arrays, you could do something like this to create the necessary array of 4 sets of coordinates:

```
function getRectCoords(x1y1, x2y2){
  var coordsArray = [];   // Empty array to hold the 4 points

  coordsArray.push(x1y1); // Push bottom left point, [x1, y1] 
  coordsArray.push(       // Push top left point, [x1, y2]
    [ x1y1[0], x2y2[1] ] 
  );
  coordsArray.push(x2y2); // Push top right point, [x2, y2]
  coordsArray.push(       // Push bottom right point, [x2, y1] 
    [ x2y2[0], x1y1[1] ]
  );

  return coordsArray;     // [ [x1, y1], [x1, y2], [x2, y2], [x2, y1] ]
}
```

Then, in ZingChart, you could call your function from within the chart JSON, like this:

```
...
"scale-y":{
    "values":"0:10:1",
    "markers":[
        {
            "type":"poly",
            "background-color":"#EA212D",
            "alpha":1.0,
            "range":getRectCoords(first_x1y1, first_x2y2),
            "value-range":true
        }
    ]
}
...
```

You can check out all of that in [this demo](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/6YGKWDO3).

I'm not sure what your data looks like, but you should be able to see from the above example that ZingChart is pretty flexible, and that with a dash of creativity, you can accomplish a lot, especially when you use JavaScript in conjunction with ZingChart.

Let me know if I can do anything else to help!